# Nix does not trigger rebuild of coreutils

Tags: build, nix

I am running Nix on top of Devuan GNU/Linux system (x86_64), with following `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`, as documented in [Nix Pills](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/nixpkgs-overriding-packages.html#idm140737315528160):

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    coreutils = pkgs.coreutils.override {
      aclSupport = false;
      attrSupport = false;
      selinuxSupport = false;
    };
    coreutils2 = pkgs.coreutils.override {
      aclSupport = false;
      attrSupport = false;
      selinuxSupport = false;
    };
    w3m = pkgs.w3m.override {
      graphicsSupport = false;
      imlib2 = null;
      x11Support = false;
      mouseSupport = true;
    };
  };
}
```

But when I run `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.coreutils`, Nix installs stock version of coreutils, with optional features enabled:

```
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.coreutils
replacing old 'coreutils-8.31'
installing 'coreutils-8.31'
$ ldd /home/iu/.nix-profile/bin/ls |grep libattr
        libattr.so.1 => /nix/store/5xwmn6ai8c42j84k6gdzja0lnkdi3c60-attr-2.4.48/lib/libattr.so.1
(0x00007f0354e7f000)
```

But if I refer to same derivation (referential transparency) via other name:

```
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.coreutils2
```

Nix starts rebuild from source, which results in binaries, compiled *without* optional features, just as requested. What is even more mysterious, overriding build options for `w3m` works and *do* trigger rebuild.

Also, I noticed same strange behavior with `gnutar`. Is is somehow related to the fact that `coreutils` and `gnutar` are essential to Nix itself? How can I make `coreutils` in expected way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [one final overlay](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d9a83d34c8da87aab5f769dcb715e1aa4bf6e043/pkgs/top-level/stage.nix#L244) is applied after your overlays. (You're using `packageOverrides` which becomes essentially the first user overlay)

To quote the [commit](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/fefa9ef756298e6863ece2e93bd057124b78452f):

> The stdenvOverrides overlay is used to bring packages forward during
>   bootstrapping via stdenv.overrides.  These packages have already had
>   the overlays applied to them in the previous boostrapping stage.  If
>   stdenvOverrides is not last in the overlays stack, all remaining
>   overlays will windup being applied again to these packages.

`gnutar` is also set by this overlay.

```
$ nix repl '<nixpkgs>'
nix-repl> lib.attrNames (stdenv.overrides pkgs pkgs)
[ "acl" "attr" "bash" "binutils" "binutils-unwrapped" "bzip2" "coreutils" "diffutils" "findutils" "gawk" "gcc" "glibc" "gnugrep" "gnumake" "gnupatch" "gnused" "gnutar" "gzip" "patchelf" "pcre" "xz" "zlib" ]
```

The "good" news is you can use a normal overlay to configure the last overlay. It's convoluted but it works:

```
nix-repl> (import <nixpkgs> { overlays = [ (self: super: { stdenv = super.stdenv // { overrides = self2: super2: super.stdenv.overrides self2 super2 // { coreutils = "put your coreutils here"; }; }; }) ]; }).coreutils
"put your coreutils here"
```

I recommend using overlays instead of `packageOverrides` to make sure this happens in the last "user" overlay.
So your overlay would be similar to:

```
_: super:
let
  coreutils = pkgs.coreutils.override {
    aclSupport = false;
    attrSupport = false;
    selinuxSupport = false;
  };
in
{
  # Overrides for stuff from stdenv go here. They're applied last
  # so we use the same stdenv for builds but a custom coreutils etc for
  # our system. This allows use to still use cache.nixos.org.
  stdenv = super.stdenv // {
    overrides = self2: super2: super.stdenv.overrides self2 super2 // {
      inherit coreutils;
    };
  };

  w3m = ...;
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant `s/pkgs/super/` (otherwise `super` is undefined). But otherwise it works. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, no. It fails to recompile `perl`. Will ask new question.