# Failed to re-compile coreutils with overrides with Nix

Tags: build, nix, gnu-coreutils

As discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758367/nix-does-not-trigger-rebuild-of-coreutils/58765599#58765599), overriding attributes of derivations, that are essential to Nix itself is more complicated than usual.

I tried to use code, provided in example, and encountered more problems. Here is my `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/main.nix`:

```
_: super:
let coreutils = super.coreutils.override { aclSupport = false; };
in
{
  stdenv = super.stdenv // {
    overrides = self2: super2:
      super.stdenv.overrides self2 super2 // {
        inherit coreutils;
    };
  };
}
```

Now when I try to install my version of coreutils with `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.coreutils --show-trace`, I get following error:

```
replacing old 'coreutils-8.31'
installing 'coreutils-8.31'
error: while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'coreutils-8.31' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'builder' of the derivation 'gmp-6.1.2' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/gmp/6.x.nix:9:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'shell' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:103:14:
while evaluating the attribute 'gcc' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix:290:7:
while evaluating 'makeOverridable' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:67:24, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix:290:13:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:8:1, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:69:16:
while evaluating the attribute 'gcc-unwrapped' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix:258:7:
while evaluating the attribute 'gcc-unwrapped.override' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:7666:3:
while evaluating 'addMetaAttrs' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/meta.nix:15:28, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:7825:10:
while evaluating 'wrapCC' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:8688:12, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:7825:19:
while evaluating 'wrapCCWith' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:8667:5, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:8688:16:
while evaluating 'callPackageWith' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:117:35, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:8676:7:
while evaluating 'makeOverridable' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:67:24, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:121:8:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:8:1, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:69:16:
while evaluating the attribute 'cc.nativeTools' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:148:14:
while evaluating 'makeOverridable' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:67:24, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix:101:19:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:8:1, called from /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:69:16:
while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'glibc-2.27' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/glibc/common.nix:167:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'depsBuildBuild' of the derivation 'linux-headers-4.19.16' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'bintools' of the derivation 'bootstrap-stage2-gcc-wrapper' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:96:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'bintools_bin' of the derivation 'binutils-wrapper-2.31.1' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/bintools-wrapper/default.nix:76:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'binutils-2.31.1' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/tools/misc/binutils/default.nix:26:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'stdenv' of the derivation 'zlib-1.2.11' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/zlib/default.nix:18:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'defaultNativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'bootstrap-stage1-stdenv-linux' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:73:14:
while evaluating the attribute 'bintools' of the derivation 'bootstrap-stage1-gcc-wrapper' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:96:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'coreutils_bin' of the derivation 'bootstrap-stage0-binutils-wrapper' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/bintools-wrapper/default.nix:76:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'buildInputs' of the derivation 'coreutils-8.31' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'attr-2.4.48' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/attr/default.nix:4:3:
while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'gettext-0.19.8.1' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'bison-3.4.2' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'postInstall' of the derivation 'perl-5.30.0' at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/interpreters/perl/default.nix:29:5:
cannot coerce null to a string, at /nix/store/dmdqvlxfk7c5gj4jg8iv77d8bmyk3c12-nixpkgs-20.03pre199995.895874d2145/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/interpreters/perl/default.nix:128:7
```

I fail to understand what is going on, this null-coercion happens somewhere in `postInstall`. Okay, I try to override `perl` too:

```
_: super:
let coreutils = super.coreutils.override { aclSupport = false; };
in
{
  stdenv = super.stdenv // {
    overrides = self2: super2:
      super.stdenv.overrides self2 super2 // {
        inherit coreutils;
        perl = super.perl.overrideAttrs (_: { postInstall = ""; });
    };
  };
}
```

Now, attempt to install `coreutils` triggers rebuild of `perl` (of course), which fails with error about missing C compiler:

```
./UU/checkcc: line 10: cc: command not found
```

And here I am stuck. So, how to override `coreutils`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think setting's perls postInstall to "" is the cause of your error. I would ignore that and go back to the very first error. And then look up the nix file at that error's position.

You'll need to clone down nixpkgs, checkout the same commit you're on, and inspect the file which looks something like:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/bc77ec7e560672ff9f8a5b5e60f228818d230d4b/pkgs/development/interpreters/perl/default.nix#L127

```
    postInstall =
      ''
        # Remove dependency between "out" and "man" outputs.
        rm "$out"/lib/perl5/*/*/.packlist
        # Remove dependencies on glibc and gcc
        sed "/ *libpth =>/c    libpth => ' '," \
          -i "$out"/lib/perl5/*/*/Config.pm
```